# Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am working on an existing asp.net application in VS 2010 in which crystal reports are using. I installed mistakenly Crystal Reports 11 around 500 MB setup. Later on I uninstalled this version and install correct version CRruntime_13_1 which is compatible with VS 2010 SP1. The problem is this when I build an asp.net application it creates the Crystal Reports dll files of version 13. something and give the following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

and assembly references in project

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

then I manualy delete these dll files and reload the page and application starts. Please tell me how to get rid of this pain because each time I build the application it creates dlls. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked which Assemblies are referenced in the project?

Comment: @Jaques: Edit is done for you.